# VSIXInstaller.exe has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Whenever I try to install any vsix files (VS add-ins) I get this error

[image]

Has anyone ran into this issue, if so how did you resolve it?

```
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3 
Problem Signature 01: vsixinstaller.exe 
Problem Signature 02: 11.0.0.0 
Problem Signature 03: 4e55a814 
Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Implementation 
Problem Signature 05: 11.0.0.0 Problem Signature 06: 4e55d338 
Problem Signature 07: 378 
Problem Signature 08: 47 
Problem Signature 09: System.TypeLoadException 
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1 
Locale ID: 1033 
Additional Information 1: 0a9e 
Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789 
Additional Information 3: 0a9e
```

Comment: Perhaps take a look at the "Problem Details" it's offering, and see if that sheds any light on it?

Comment: That really doesn't shed any insight on the problem. I'll paste what it shows in a new answer (too long for a comment)

Comment: Dont paste it into an answer - hit EDIT and add it to your post

Comment: Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: vsixinstaller.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 11.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 4e55a814
  Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Implementation
  Problem Signature 05: 11.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4e55d338
  Problem Signature 07: 378
  Problem Signature 08: 47
  Problem Signature 09: System.TypeLoadException
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e

Comment: Which version/edition of VS? Anything in the system event logs?  What have you already tried?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. There's nothing in the event logs that sheds any light . I tried rebooting to see if that helps anything. I tried a couple more VSIX files to make sure it wasn't just the one I was trying to install initially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think (unfortunately) you've found yourself a little piece of DLL hell.

If you're lucky it's just a conflicting plug-in.  Try removing all other VS extensions and plug-ins and then adding one of the problematic ones to see if it works.

I'd also do a `chkdsk` and a `sfc /checknow` to see if there's been any system file corruption.

Then perhaps try removing, [fully cleaning](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301085724/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx) and reinstalling all versions of .Net, and then perhaps Visual Studio itself.

If it used to work OK, maybe try a [System Restore](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/) first.

Comment: I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling VS 2010 to get it semi working right.